Showing that the set $(0,1]$ is not compact.
Is the following a correct way of showing that the set $(0,1]$ is not compact or I am missing something.
We will prove that it does not satisfy the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, i.e., there exists a sequence in $E=(0,1]$ with a converging subsequence that does not have a limit in $(0,1].$\
Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined by $\{\frac{1}{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$i.e., we have $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \dots).$ Clearly $\{a_n\} \subset (0,1]$ and it is bounded by 1. Then, if we take it as a subsequence of itself, we see that its limit is $0$ which is not in $(0,1]$ hence $(0,1]$ is not compact as required.

The Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem states that "Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence." It is not a statement about intervals or subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about whether $(0,1]$ "satisfies" the theorem.

That is not correct for two reasons. The first reason lies in the statement of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem; it should be stated as “every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence”.
Then there is the problem that you have only proved that the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ doesn't converge. You should have proved that no subsequence of that sequence converges. That's not hard: every such subsequence converges to $0$, and therefore doesn't converge in $(0,1]$.

But I said it does not satisfy it, so I am just writing the negation of your statement.

The negation of the statement “every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence” is “there is a bounded sequence with no convergent subsequence”, and I proved that this is true. Don't you agree?

Yes you did. I am sorry I tried to vote you up but it is now locked, you can delete your answer and I delete the question

You can upvote my answer now (and accept it, if you wish).

you can also upvote my question if you wish to
